# My laptop has heavy CPU load when playing SOME games

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cpu-usage, gaming, lag

I just got my hands on a used Alienware 13 R3 with these specs:

- QuadCore Intel Core i7-7700HQ, 3400 MHz (34 x 100) , 6MB cache
- 12157 MB RAM (12 GB)
- nVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 (Dell) , 6 GB vRam (DirectX v12)
- Intel HD Graphics 630 (On Board Graphics Card , 1GB)
- Windows 10 64bit
- 128 GB SSD

Where problem starts is that this only happens when I play some Games not all,
I played Wolfenstein Old Blood with no lag,
Wolfenstein New Order with minor lags (when played for long and on certain parts only),
but Played ROTTR and the lags are happening every 5 seconds, and even on Low graphics settings the same happens.

This happens with the CPU going on more than 80% load and overheating, usually on the 90 degrees to 100 degrees (Celsius), but the graphics card works like in other games, and objects are loaded with relevant graphics quality.

I also have an antivirus active so my Laptop Can't be infected.

can anyone point why this is happening? The system I have is relatively acceptable , at least for running most games released before 2017, 2018. so I can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: First of all, the fact that you have an antivirus software installed does not mean that it cannot be infected. Second, when did you do the last clean install of windows? If it is still the windows installation that was on it when you bought it, maybe the problem lies within someting that the previous owner did, not anything we could read from the facts you gave us.

Comment: Yeah I know but that reduces the chance of being infected a lot, specially for older viruses and threats. two weeks ago, so it's a pretty new installation of windows.  well yeah but what could cause the problem? specially since this happens only when playing some games

Comment: If it only happens under heavy (or particular) load it might be that your fans need cleaning and the thermal pastes need replacing. If you are regularly hitting 100C then something needs looking at with your cooling.

Comment: @It does not usually hit that much and like I said it is not necessary Heavy load but rather some games, as for the fans, I don't know if they need cleaning, I will try it , but I enabled the performance settings for the fans, so they run pretty loud (and seemingly with enough power) and the system is cooled sufficently enough with this feature active , at least when using it for purposes other than gaming. although I have to get a good coolpad for it first and see if the problem goes away or happpens less or not. still it only happens with some of the games, not all.

Comment: If your hitting 90c to 100c your cooling system isn't working properly either due to dust or the system is insufficient.  I would buy a can of compressed air and blow out all the fans, and see if that helps.  If not, your going to have to open it up, and make sure to blow out all the dust.

Comment: @cybernard ok I will try that too, and get back here with the result